# Undoing the color change of the boxes in the reverse order that they were clicked (using HTML, CSS, Jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm a newbie to front end development. I'm creating few boxes using HTML, CSS and jquery. I want to change the color of boxes to blue as I click on them. After all the boxes are clicked and the color is changed(to blue), I want to undo the blue color of the boxes in the reverse order they were clicked (Boxes should not be clickable during the change). After all the boxes are undone, the boxes should become clickable again. Thanks for the help.

Question edit:
I have created few boxes in html, css and jquery. After clicking on the box, it's color changes. After all the boxes are changed to blue color, I want to undo the blue color of the boxes in the reverse order they were clicked. Thanks.

EDIT:
So far I have created the boxes and I'm able to click the boxes and change its color to blue. But I need some help with the undoing part.
I have worked on the Jquery code. Can someone please check for errors?

Comment: That looks perfectly right.

Comment: Your code shows no effort to actually do the thing.

Comment: What code you've written looks fine. (Didn't look at the markup, but I see a lot of inline styling that would better be moved to a stylesheet.) Keep going. If you get struck, as a specific question about what it is that has you stuck. *"But I need some help with the undoing part."* What aspect of it? When to trigger it? How to undo them in order? How to keep track of the order in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How do I keep track of the order? and how to undo them after that?

Comment: What are you trying to do.

Comment: To be able to undo coloring, you have to maintain all the clicks in JS and prepare a code that after all the required clicks are registered, undoes coloring. It should be simple, e.g. you could maintain some kind of array with the clicks and each click is represented by false(not clicked)/true(clicked already). After each click you could iterate over array to check if it contains only true ones.

Comment: Thanks SzybkiSasza :)

Comment: @PraveenKumar Can you help me with the javascript? I have posted my javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're just looking to be pointed in the right direction so...

As mentioned put your inline styles into your star class:

```
style="border:1px solid #000;"
```

can be...

```
.star {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

This is just tidies up the HTML a little and makes it easier to maintain.

Next you're going to need to record the order that your boxes (divs) are clicked in.  To do this you'll need to identify them.  One way to do this is to ad a unique ID to each one...

```
<div class="star" id="box1"> </div>
<div class="star" id="box2"> </div>
etc
```

Now in your JS code you will need to...

1) Record each ID (box) as it is clicked (into an array)

2) Check the length of your array, if it is full (equals the total number of boxes) then you are ready to undo the colouring in reverse order

3) Go through your list in reverse order, undoing the colouring.  You will probably want to use setTimeout() to put a delay between undoing it (otherwise JS will be too quick to notice and they'll all happen at the same time) and maybe use a transition to fade the colour out (looks nicer than instantaneous change).

The tricky parts in your code will be handling what happens if you click on a box that has already been clicked on (you could check the array, if that id already exists then exit and do nothing) and disabling the clicking during the undo phase (global var called disableClick which is set to true when undoing and onclick you check this and don't do anything if true).

So lots of work to do in the code...

```
$('.star').click(function(){
  // check if in undo phase, exit if true
  // check if box already clicked, exit if true
  // get current box id and add to array
  // check if array is full and initiate undo phase if it is
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Quantumplate :)

Comment: 1) Put the inline style in your star class as mentioned.  2) You have a LOT of repetition, it's usually a sign you can simplify things, for your event handlers you only need one rather than one per div, e.g. $('.star').click(function() { ... }  3) you can similarly reduce your large if (arr[i] == "1") { statement to a couple of lines (each one is doing the same thing, just a different div number.  Once you've simplified these it will be much easier to read, understand.

Answer (score 1):

Like Quantumplate said but use this as your event handler

```
 $('.star').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
 });
```

to

```
 $('div').delegate(".star","click", function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('star');

 });
```

as the class is removed, it becomes unclickable, as it is added back in, it can be clicked without writing more code to add the handler back in.